# How can I couple MCNP with FLUKA? To attain reactor dynamics and simulate an ADS experiment? (Under Subcritical fast system)

Tags: python, computational-physics, software

I'm new in Particle Physics based Computing. I want to simulate an ADS experiment (Accelerator Driven System) in subcritical fast system. I was advised to simulate the experiment with FLUKA with MCNP being coupled with it.

On the otherhand, I saw CERN now uses Flair more than FLUKA. is FLUKA and Flair same and if someone can mention how I can couple Flair with MCNP that will be helpful!

I don't know how to actually couple both of them with each other. If anyone can help me out or suggest something that would be wonderful?

**(Edited) Note:** I'm trying to analyze Nuclear waste Neutralization using proton beam through [ADS concept](https://world-nuclear.org/information-library/current-and-future-generation/accelerator-driven-nuclear-energy.aspx). And I don't know to couple MCNP with FLUKA!

FLUKA: http://www.fluka.org/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've added additional details and provided with the software website link.